# % cannot be assigned to decimal type C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a data type of type decimal.

I want to carry out following:

```
 if(decimalData % 0.25 !=0)
 {
     //do some manipulation
 }
```

But it is giving me the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should help you with decimal.

```
if(decimalData % 0.25M !=0)
{
 //do some manipulation
}
```

A "real literal" without suffix or with the d or D suffix is of type double. You could read more on [suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals) here

- Suffix for Decimal - M or m
- Suffix for float - F or f
- Suffix for
  Double - Without any suffix or D/d